# C# WPF Toolkit Chart: Bind with 16k points speed

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit

When *Chart* is binding to 16000 points binding speed is very slow.

I have Chart (Wpf toolkit):

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart ... DataContext="{Binding Data}" ... >
```

Data is a property in *ViewModel* (MVVM pattern I use):

```
public List<Point> Data { get { return series; } }
```

series is a field:

```
private List<Point> series;
```

In constructor of ViewModel:

```
for ( ... ; ...;  ... )
{
  y = ...
  series.Add(new Point((i * scale), y));
}
```

When I try bind chart to data program will freeze about 1-2 minutes then OK. I made same program on WinForms - speed is perfect. Any idea how to fix this bind issue?

Comment: I might be wrong, but is it necessary that a chart has 16k points?

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to reduce the number of points. You'll generally notice that having lots of WPF elements on a control causes performance issues and generally their WinForm counter parts are fine.

In the case of the chart I imagine circles and lines are being used, and remembered in the WPF tree structure, so that 16k elements+ that WPF is remembering. It might be better to try embedding a WinForms chart in WPF instead, something that is more like a canvas and once drawn forgets about the point....